# How to check whether connection pooling is working or not in java?

Tags: java, tcp, connection-pooling

I am using [`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html) and my code is working fine but I want to know whether my code is using [`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html) resource 
i have integrated it with [`CloseableHttpClient`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient.html) like below

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();    
cm.setMax(3);    
    client = HttpClients.custom()
                        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                        .setConnectionManager(cm)
                        .build();
```

So I have tried using wire shark and filtered using `tcp.flags.ack==0 && tcp.flags.syn==1`

When I use this I am seeing ssl hand shake is being made for every request 
For example I am using a for loop in which it makes 10 requests to server like below

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 {

    CloseableHttpResponse response2 = client.execute(httpPost);
    response2.close();
 }
```

I am seeing 10 TCP packets created (Tracked) for above requests. Am I using [`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html) in a wrong way or it is right?

**Update :**
Adding Imports
My Complete Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.config.Registry;
import org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder;
import org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.glassfish.jersey.SslConfigurator;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;  
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test{
static PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm;
static CloseableHttpClient client;

static String path="www.example.com";    
static
    {


    SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance()
            .securityProtocol("TLS")
            .keyStoreFile("/path")
            .keyStorePassword("passw")
            .keyStoreType("JKS")
            .trustStoreFile("/path");

    SSLContext sslCtx = sslConfig.createSSLContext();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslCtx,NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
    HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();


    final Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
            .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
            .register("https", sslSocketFactory)
            .build();


    cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);

    client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .build();

}
public static void main(String a[]) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException
{

    JSONObject jsonResponse;
    JsonObject jsonRequest = null;
    jsonRequest.addProperty("id","number");



     StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonRequest.toString());

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(path);
    httpPost.setEntity(se);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    CloseableHttpResponse response2; 
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");



    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
        response2 = client.execute(httpPost);

    System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine());
    HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();

    String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity2);
    System.out.println(result);

    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
   response2.close();
   }

}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You already almost did it, but it's not complete.

Comment: i have provided my code in update

Comment: @ Ortomala Lokni is there any solution

Comment: The code will be really complete with `import` statements.

Comment: i have updated imports

Comment: Variables `client`, `path` and `jsonRequest` are not defined.

Comment: path is the string url , json Request is a JsonObject which is sent to Server in post method

Comment: Client is Javax.ws.rs.client Client client; 
For your reference i have added those vailables also in above code check

Comment: Your code still has at least three compile time errors. Try to provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You use `jsonRequest.addProperty("id","number");` without having initialized `jsonRequest`. You should run your code before posting it.

Comment: in my code it is initialized to null i cant copy paste my code here as it is that is why sorry

Comment: If it's initialized to `null` you will have a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: i am adding property after that to it , it will over right null value

Answer (score 0):

Execute a transaction from open to close, and then look at `netstat` to see if the TCP connection to the database is still ESTABLISHED after you closed the `Connection.`

Comment: but there is no connection pooling for jdbc in my code

Comment: So execute an *HTTP* transaction. Same difference.

Comment: i am checking in wire shark and i have said results above is it wrong?

i will try netstat

Comment: in netstat also i am seeing 10 tcp ports are being used from 51079 to 51089

Comment: in wire shark i made filter tcp.flags.syn == 1 && tcp.flags.ack ==0 there also 10 packets are captured

Comment: in netstat i am seeing 10 ports are being kept alive at any time after 10 requests if i use 50 requests in loop